# How do I ask the user for an integer in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I would like to ask the user for an integer input using AppleScript but I am unable to find how to do that. When I use `set userInput to display dialogue "Please enter a number." default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel","Continue"} default button "Continue"`, it stores the input as a string. How can I convert `userInput` to an integer or how can I ask for an integer input? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The result of the dialog is a _record_, so you will need to get the _text returned_.  From there, you can coerce the string to an integer, possibly including a `try` statement if the coercion fails (e.g. not a number).  See the [Mac Automation Scripting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/PromptforText.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH80-SW1) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It worked.